# linux repo no enabled setting

Tags: linux, repository, yum

I'm doing an audit of the repos on one of our servers and noticed that in some cases there is no enabled setting. Would it default to enabled or disabled in that case (so that I can add the flag in, for clarity).

Thanks

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: @kaylum Fair point. I'll delete the question shortly, if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/yum.conf.5.html) of `yum.conf` the default value is `enabled=true`

So if you do not have this option explicitly defined you can assume this repo is enabled.

Comment: Thank you (sorry I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer)

Comment: @Len, if you are happy with the answer you can accept it (tick under the number on the left of answer) :)